# Measurability of sets which satisfy the additivity of measure

Tags: measure-theory

E is measurable, and E is a disjoint union of E1, E2. I want to show that
 if m(E)= m*(E1)+m*(E2) then E1 and E2 are measurable. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706592/) your problem?

Comment: If $m(E)=+\infty$, the result is false. Example: Take $E_1$ to be any non-measurable set  in $\mathbb{R}$ and $E_2$ to be $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_1$. We have that $\mathbb{R}$ is the disjoint union of $E_1$ and $E_2$ and $$ +\infty =m(\mathbb{R})=m^*(E_1)+m^*(E_2)$$ However, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not measurable.

Comment: What if the condition added? E has  finite measure.